# How feed a table with multiple foreign keys from different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

so I have 3 models :

```
 public class Contact
 {
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int SegmentID { get; set; }
    public Segment Segment { get; set; }
 }

 public class MedicalPlan
 { 
    public int MedicalPlanID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int SegmentID { get; set; }
    public Segment Segment { get; set; }
 }

 public class Target 
 {
    public int TargetID { get; set; }
    public int MedicalPlanID { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public MedicalPlan MedicalPlan { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
 }
```

A MedicalPlan got many Contacts, and Target got both many MedicalPlans and Contacts,

Now Each MedicalPlan has a buttom called generate: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lg7S.png)

What I want is when you press that buttom it creates a Target and generates every Contacts that are associated to that MedicalPlan through SegmentID and insert them in the table Target as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j34ty.png)

I've tried something like this :

```
                    IEnumurable<int> cons =
                        from contact in contacts
                        where contact.SegmentID == planMedical.SegmentID
                        select contact.ContactID;

                        int[] res = cons.ToArray();
                       


                        for ( int j = 0; j < res.Length ; j++)
                        {
                            targets.PlanMedicalID = id; //id MedicalPlans current row's key
                            targets.ContactID = res[j];
                            _context.Add(targets);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
```

But it does nothing..

Comment: Where did you define ```targets``` can you show?

Comment: Here : `public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(int id, PlanMedical planMedical, PlanTarget targets) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating you `ViewModel` which is `PlanTargets`, but you have to create you `Database` Model Entity, you have to create the object as:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < res.Length ; j++)
{
    var target = new Target //ADD THIS LINE
    {
        MedicalPlanID = id,
        ContactID = res[j] ​
   ​ };
    _context.Target.Add(target);
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**You are not creating a `Target` object, you are creating a `PlanTargets` object and trying to add it to your DbContext.**

**NOTE:** In your scenerio, you want to create a `Target` object for **every** `ContactID`, so in your `for loop` you have to create the object with the `new` keyword, and set the related properties, after that you have to add it to your DbContext, and when you `SaveChanges` then it will save the results to your database.

Comment: That target table is called PlanTarget in my models, I was shortening the names so it's not annoying.. anways it worked when I add that line, thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, for your information, you can only add the ```DbSet<Entity>``` defined in your ```DbContext``` to your database through EntityFramework :)